# Searching a .txt file for multiple list terms and outputting counts/%/words

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm trying to search through a given .txt file (source_filename) for a series of list terms and provide their count output, % of those terms in the .txt file, and exact words for each set of listed terms found in the text.

How should I set up the count/reporting feature?

```py
#build GUI for text file selection
import PySimpleGUI as sg      
window_rows = [[sg.Text('Please select a .txt file for analysis')],      
                 [sg.InputText(), sg.FileBrowse()],      
                 [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]      
window = sg.Window('Cool Tool Name', window_rows)    
event, values = window.Read()    
window.Close()
source_filename = values[0]    

#written communication term list
dwrit = ('write','written','writing', 'email', 'memo')
written = dwrit

#oral communication term list
doral = ('oral','spoken','talk','speech,')
oral = doral 

#visual communication term list
dvis = ('visual','sight') 
visual = dvis

#auditory communication term list
daud = ('hear', 'hearing', 'heard')
auditory = daud

#multimodal communication term list
dmm = ('multimodal','multi-modal','mixed media','audio and visual')
multimodal = dmm

#define all term lists 
communication = (dwrit, doral, dvis, daud, dmm)

#search lists
from collections import Counter
with open(source_filename, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') as f:
     for line in f:
         Counter.update(line.lower().split())
print(Counter(communication))
```

**The problem is,** I'm printing out *all* the terms in *all* lists right now, but I'm not actually searching the document *just* for those listed terms and ignoring all other terms...

The ideal output would look like:

Written: [number, %, words]

Oral: [number, %, words]

Visual: [number, %, words]

Auditory: [number, %, words]

Multimodal: [number, %, words]

Comment: To get the graphs you mentioned (distributions), you can go 2 ways.  One is to draw the graphs by hand using the Graph element and the line / rectangle drawing primitives.  The other is to use Matplotlib which PySimpleGUI integrates with.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeyB! I'm having difficulty with actually searching through the lists I have (dwrit, doral, etc.) and finding just those terms in the .txt file. That's the first step in getting to where I can output visualizations. 

When I use print(Counter(communication)), it just prints ALL of the terms in all of the lists.

Comment: Look at the examples in the Demo Folder on the PySimpleGUI GitHub page.  They're label clearly with matplotlib and pyplot.

Answer (score 0):

The Counter is a dictionary which is keyed off the thing you are counting.  So that is why you are seeing every single word, you didn't just lookup the words (as keys in the Counter) that correspond to the words you are interested in.  Below is an example of how you might do one of the items, this is a pattern you can use to do the other lists.

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
#search lists
with open(source_filename, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') as f:
    for line in f:
        c.update(line.lower().split())
written_words = len([x for x in written if x in c.keys()])
print(f'Written: [{written_words}, {written_words/len(c.keys())} %]')
```

Comment: `len([x for x in c.keys() if x in written])` You'd be much better off going through the words in the `written` list than the `Counter()`, as it defaults to 0. More efficient on a large file.

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelD! This seems like a great way to do it, and I can pattern this for the other communication types, very nifty! I'm getting the error: "SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'"

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced the ) when I fixed the previous typo.

Comment: @RobertC, if this is the best answer to your question please mark it as answered.